# Creating an Image with Bitmap image option in word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I encountered a strange image in a word document with a "Bitmap image object" option as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to create such an object?

Comment: Which version of Word? 2013?

Comment: Yes its word 2013

Comment: I also verified that this option appears in word 2007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To create a new bitmap image:**

1. Click the Object button on the Insert ribbon.
2. Select "Bitmap Image" and click OK.
3. Create your image
4. Close Microsoft Paint
5. The image will appear in your document.

**For an existing bitmap image (.bmp file):**

1. Click the Object button on the Insert ribbon.
2. Click "Create from file" (tab)
3. Click Browse
4. Select a .bmp file
5. Click OK and the image will appear in your document

Comment: Thank you for the response. I cannot seem to find an "Object" button under the insert ribbon. Exactly where is this button?

Comment: http://www.softwareask.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/06-Selecting-Object-from-Insert-Tab.png